# ETL process in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am doing ETL process in Spark using scala.
raw log file contains two column name and age. My ETL process read and validate raw log and generate two more column i.e flag and validation message.
Flag column specify that whether row is valid not not.(if row is valid= 1 else 0)
validation column specify why row is not valid.

Ex.
Raw log file

```
RAM,35
SAM,45
JAM,ww
```

Here last row is invalid so my final output will be

```
RAM,35,1,""
SAM,45,1,""
JAM,ww,0,"invalid age"
```

My scala code is

```
import sqlContext._

val people = sc.textFile("hdfs://..../rawT.csv").map(_.split(","))

val base_people = people.map{r => val formatted_people = if(r(1).matches("^\\d*$")) ("1","") else ("0","Invalid Age");  (r(0), r(1), formatted_people)}
```

But in this code RDD is getting generated as 
`base_people: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, (String, String))]`

And I want RDD without string array,
`base_people: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, String)]`

Is my logic is correct OR Do I need to follow some other code stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a triple with a pair in the last position, instead of a quad. How about:

```
val base_people = people
  .map{r => if(r(1).matches("^\\d*$"))
              (r(0), r(1), "1", "") 
            else 
              (r(0), r(1), "0", "Invalid Age")}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is so many ways to do what you are trying to achieve. Here is how I'll do it :

```
val base_people = data.map{
  r => r(1) match {
   case i:Int => (r(0), r(1), "1", "") 
   case s:String => (r(0), r(1), "0", "invalid age")
  }
}
```

I'll use pattern matching on the second field with case classes  (Int,String,Double, etc.) . You can use whatever class suits you.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You can valid the answer and up-vote if you consider the answer to be correct